# NSInvalidArgumentException when loading a TableViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I've got a button on a `ViewController` to load a `TableViewController`. The code behind the button is:

```
- (IBAction)loadSearchView:(id)sender {

SearchTableViewController *searchVC = [[SearchTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:searchVC animated:YES]; }
```

When the `TableViewController` loads, the app crashes with the following error:

> 2013-02-21 15:22:19.460 MyMusicLibrary[4159:c07] -[UITableView
>   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x7aa0800 2013-02-21 15:22:19.462
>   MyMusicLibrary[4159:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableView
>   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x7aa0800'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x14b5022 0xeb5cd6 0x14b6cbd 0x141bed0 0x141bcb2 0x3279 0xb2c54 0xb33ce 0x9ecbd 0xad6f1 0x56d21 0x14b6e42
>   0x1d86679 0x1d90579 0x1d154f7 0x1d173f6 0x1d16ad0 0x148999e 0x1420640
>   0x13ec4c6 0x13ebd84 0x13ebc9b 0x139e7d8 0x139e88a 0x18626 0x1fdd
>   0x1f05) terminate called throwing an exception

The code it is trying to run on load of the TableViewController is:

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [[cell textLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %i", [indexPath row]]];

    return cell;
}
```

The numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection are set as follows:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 10;
}
```

However, when these are both set to 0, the table view loads. Can anyone help? :)

Comment: Have you set the datasource and delegate correctly?

Comment: What version of iOS are you using? That is a valid method as of iOS 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use just only

```
 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cellidentifier"
```

like this

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cellidentifier"];
```

Comment: Thanks got it! So new to iOS... :)

Comment: [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:] is available only iOS 6.0 and later.

Answer (score -1):

There is no tableview method available `- (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath:`  ,   you just need to pass only identifier for

```
- (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
```

Comment: Yes, in fact there is such a method.

Comment: Yes its available in iOS 6.0 and later

Comment: Yes. Do you not see it in your documentation? If not, then you need to update your document set.